# Change the Text Color of the Selected Text in TextField

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm looking for a way to get the index of a selected text from my text field and change its color. For example, if I have the text:

Hello Friends

and I select "Fri", I want to change its color.

Important Note: The text content is dynamic and users can type using the keyboard. I cannot enforce any specific conditions or rules. I just want the selected text to change its color.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a link to https://dartpad.dev/ so that we can replicate this issue?

Comment: I hope this package will help you https://pub.dev/packages/appflowy_editor

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you

```
                 Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 20, 20, 20),
                    child: RichText(
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      text: TextSpan(
                        // Note: Styles for TextSpans must be explicitly defined.
                        // Child text spans will inherit styles from parent
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 14.0,
                          color: Colors.black,
                        ),
                        children: <TextSpan>[
                          TextSpan(
                              text: "By continuing, I agree to the ",
                              style: Styles.googleFontBlack),
                          TextSpan(
                              text: "Terms of Use ",
                              style: Styles.googleFontRedBold),
                          TextSpan(
                              text: "&  ",
                              style: Styles.googleFontBlack),
                          TextSpan(
                              text: "Privacy Policy ",
                              style: Styles.googleFontRedBold),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
```

RichText & TextSpan is your key to achieve the output you are expecting.